# Rebuild Q path segments into pieces in JavaScript/SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, path, curve, bezier

There is an SVG elements with few paths (polygons) having adjacent sides.

```
<svg id="dummyIn" viewBox="0 0 800 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <path id="poly0" d="M200 296.6L400 187.6L400 285L200 346.2Z" fill="#005f73" />
    <path id="poly1" d="M200 346.2L320 309.48 Q400 285 478.6533272400307 313.51183112451116L600 357.5L600 596.7L467.8848705014076 511.6839141676558 Q400 468 320 478.8L200 495Z" fill="#0a9396" />
    <path id="poly2" d="M400 187.6L600 324.8L600 357.5L400 285Z" fill="#94d2bd" />
</svg>
```

The path named 'poly1' have two curves segments based on Q command `L320 309.48 Q400 285 478.6533272400307 313.51183112451116` and `L467.8848705014076 511.6839141676558 Q400 468 320 478.8L200 495`.

[image]

The task is to recalculate these segments in JavaScript for 'poly0' and 'poly2' in a way, so the output would be

[image]

Did an output mock-up in Adobe Illustrator by cutting these curves into segments and the output SVG is

```
<svg id="dummyOut" viewBox="0 0 800 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <path id="poly0" d="M200 296.6L400 187.6L478.7,313.5c-26.1-9.5-52.3-14.5-78.7-15.3L200 346.2Z" fill="#005f73" />
    <path id="poly1" d="M200 346.2L320 309.48 Q400 285 478.6533272400307 313.51183112451116L600 357.5L600 596.7L467.8848705014076 511.6839141676558 Q400 468 320 478.8L200 495Z" fill="#0a9396" />
    <path id="poly2" d="M400 187.6L600 324.8L600 357.5L478.7,313.5c-26.1-9.5-52.3-14.5-78.7-15.3Z" fill="#94d2bd" />
</svg>
```

In other words, the goal is to split `L320 309.48 Q400 285 478.6533272400307 313.51183112451116` into two parts `L400,298.3c-26.6-0.7-53.2,3-80,11.2` and `L478.7,313.5c-26.1-9.5-52.3-14.5-78.7-15.3`.

That's just an Illustrator solution based on C commands. But it is not obligatory.

Comment: Are you just trying to move the curve, without moving the trapezoids, so that it covers the whitespace or are you trying to move poly0.2 and poly2.3 down so that there's no whitespace (which is super simple, because once you're willing to move those points down, just move them down "all the way", the curve is going to overlay it anyway)? Effectively: are you trying to make "shapes", or are you trying to make "an image"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to calculate some interpolated points.

[image: quadratic interpolation]

- **cyan:** last point from previous command (preceding `Q`)
- **blue:**  `Q` quadratic bézier control point
- **orange:**  `Q` command end point
- **purple1+2:** middle points between cyan-blue and blue-orange – these will become the new `Q` control points
- **red:** middle point between purple1-purple2 – will become the new `L` command point.

```js
let p0 = [320, 309.48];
let p1 = [478.653, 313.512];
let cp1 = [400, 285];
renderPoint(svg, p0, 'cyan')
renderPoint(svg, p1, 'orange')
renderPoint(svg, cp1, 'blue')

let m1 = interpolatedPoint(p0, cp1);
let m2 = interpolatedPoint(cp1, p1);
renderPoint(svg, m1, 'purple')
renderPoint(svg, m2, 'purple')

let p2 = interpolatedPoint(m1, m2);
renderPoint(svg, p2, 'red');

//new segment
let d0 = `
M 200 296.6
L 400 187.6
L ${p2.x} ${p2.y}
Q ${m1.x} ${m1.y} ${p0.x} ${p0.y}
L200 346.2
`;

poly0.setAttribute('d', d0)

let d1 = `
M 400 187.6 
L 600 324.8
L 600 357.5
L ${p1.x} ${p1.y}
Q ${m2.x} ${m2.y} ${p2.x} ${p2.y}
z
`;

poly2.setAttribute('d', d1)





/**
 * Linear  interpolation (LERP) helper
 */
function interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, t = 0.5) {
    //t: 0.5 - point in the middle
    if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
        p1.x = p1[0];
        p1.y = p1[1];
    }
    if (Array.isArray(p2)) {
        p2.x = p2[0];
        p2.y = p2[1];
    }
    let [x, y] = [(p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x, (p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y];
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}


/**
 * render point
 * accepts coordinate array and point object
 **/
function renderPoint(svg, coords, fill = "red", r = "0.5%") {
    if (Array.isArray(coords)) {
        coords = {
            x: coords[0],
            y: coords[1]
        };
    }
    let marker = `<circle cx="${coords.x}" cy="${coords.y}" r="${r}" fill="${fill}">
      <title>${coords.x} ${coords.y}</title></circle>`;
    svg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", marker);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 800 800" >
    <path id="poly0" d="M200 296.6L400 187.6L400 285L200 346.2Z" fill="#005f73" />
    <path id="poly2" d="M400 187.6L600 324.8L600 357.5L400 285Z" fill="#94d2bd" />
    <path id="poly1" d="
M 200 346.2 
L 320 309.48 
Q 400 285  478.653 313.512
L 600 357.5 
L 600 596.7 
L 467.885 511.684
Q 400 468  320 478.8
L200 495Z" fill="#0a9396" />
</svg>
```

You don't really need the LERP (linear interpolation) helper method (but it's quite handy).
You can just get the middle points like so:

```
m1 = {x:(x1+x2)/2, y:(y1+y2)/2}
```

**BTW, splitting cubic béziers works similarly:**
You just need more interpolations.
See this excellent post: [The Anatomy Of A Cubic Bézier Curve In SVG](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/post/how-to-add-a-point-to-an-svg-path)